# FileSystemWatcher - monitor Alternate Data Streams

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to monitor (e.g. creation) alternate data streams using FileSystemWatcher?  Or, perhaps another way?  For my application I am not going to implement any polling mechanisms.

Thanks in advance,

Craig

Comment: So you're after something kind of like FileSystemWatcher that monitors something other than files; for example a hypothetical DataTableWatcher? (or a FooWatcher)?

Comment: Do you want to monitor other data sources like in the above comment, or an alternate file NTFS stream?

Comment: I am referring to NTFS alternate data streams--which are files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileSystemWatcher can do this by default

When you edit a file's ADS the timestamp of last modification changes so you can check for that

Afterwards you'll have to enumerate ADS for the file
[This is an example on how to do it](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/AlternateDataStream.aspx)

Comment: Sweet!  I should have noticed the change in the modified date/timestamp.  Thanks.